# Contact form test email with xampp

Tags: php, xampp, contact-form

I have a contact page that I made following [this](https://github.com/mokah/PHP-Contact-Form) tutorial, when I click send I get a message telling me that the message has been sent, but I ain't receiving any email, I'm trying to test it locally with xampp v3.1.0, I read that I have to change the smtp in php.ini, but it didn't work either.

I want to test it with my localhost, what do I have to do?

Comment: Setup a SMTP server in localhost

Comment: install mailserver, or connect to remote mail server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You often don't have mail capability from your local server unless you specifically set it up that way. If you want to be able to send mail locally, refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652566/php-mail-setup-in-xampp). Of course, there are other ways, such as installing hMailServer or some other smtp server, but you should have sendmail as part of your Xampp installation.

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen in the link "Mail" in XAMPP homepage (i.e. "localhost"), with the default configurations of the XAMPP, mails sent by the php `mail` function can be found in ".../xampp/mailoutput" folder (Windows). This is useful for test purposes.

Maybe your change to the "php.ini"s SMTP directive can be a problem to this approach.

Comment: Hey, do you know where is the mail output folder on mac? I am trying to follow your instruction but there is no mail output folder on my mac....

Comment: Sorry man, i don't know. I don't use Xampp for quite a while now, so i don't even know if the folder it's in the same place in Windows, maybe it changed in a later version.