# SMTP server with XAMPP?

Tags: php, email, xampp

I am new to php and in my project I have used php mail function, but while sending mail from database it shows an error like:

```
Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP"
```

By searching on stackoverflow and google, I come to know that XAMPP does not provide SMTP server and I will have to install a SMTP server.

I am really confused.So, Which SMTP server I  should install?

Comment: Instead of installing a SMTP server, you could use your ISP's SMTP server or Google's (if you have a GMail account). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-smtp-server

Comment: I am new to php. I don't know how to use Gmail account to send mails in php. can you better explain this in answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php mail setup in xampp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652566/php-mail-setup-in-xampp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this example, I will use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

So first, you have to download the source code of PHPMailer. Only 3 files are necessary :

- [PHPMailerAutoload.php](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/master/PHPMailerAutoload.php)
- [class.phpmailer.php](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/master/class.phpmailer.php)
- [class.smtp.php](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/master/class.smtp.php)

Put these 3 files in the same folder.
Then create the main script (I called it 'index.php').

Content of index.php :

```
<?php

//Load PHPMailer dependencies
require_once 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require_once 'class.phpmailer.php';
require_once 'class.smtp.php';

/* CONFIGURATION */
$crendentials = array(
    'email'     => 'XXXXXXXX@gmail.com',    //Your GMail adress
    'password'  => 'XXXXXXXX'               //Your GMail password
    );

/* SPECIFIC TO GMAIL SMTP */
$smtp = array(

'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => 587,
'username' => $crendentials['email'],
'password' => $crendentials['password'],
'secure' => 'tls' //SSL or TLS

);

/* TO, SUBJECT, CONTENT */
$to         = ''; //The 'To' field
$subject    = 'This is a test email sent with PHPMailer';
$content    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';



$mailer = new PHPMailer();

//SMTP Configuration
$mailer->isSMTP();
$mailer->SMTPAuth   = true; //We need to authenticate
$mailer->Host       = $smtp['host'];
$mailer->Port       = $smtp['port'];
$mailer->Username   = $smtp['username'];
$mailer->Password   = $smtp['password'];
$mailer->SMTPSecure = $smtp['secure']; 

//Now, send mail :
//From - To :
$mailer->From       = $crendentials['email'];
$mailer->FromName   = 'Your Name'; //Optional
$mailer->addAddress($to);  // Add a recipient

//Subject - Body :
$mailer->Subject        = $subject;
$mailer->Body           = $content;
$mailer->isHTML(true); //Mail body contains HTML tags

//Check if mail is sent :
if(!$mailer->send()) {
    echo 'Error sending mail : ' . $mailer->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message sent !';
}
```

You can also add 'CC', 'BCC' fields etc...

Examples and documentation can be found on [Github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

If you need to use another SMTP server, you can modify the values in `$smtp`.

**Note** : you may have a problem sending the mail, like 'Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto'.

In such case, you must enable the OpenSSL extension. Check your `phpinfo()`, look for the value of 'Loaded Configuration File' (in my case : E:\Program Files\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.2\bin\php.ini) and in this file, uncomment the line `extension=php_openssl.dll`. Then, restart your XAMPP server.

Comment: Would you mind commenting on what the main differences are in using this approach versus the sendmail approach in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652566/php-mail-setup-in-xampp) ? Both seem to work, but I am not sure why I would choose one or the other.  Thanks!