# XAMPP and PHP mail from localhost

Tags: php, email, xampp, sendmail

I need to send emails from localhost from a XAMPP installation.
I don't want to use Sendmail with a Gmail as many tutorials show.

There is any way to do work PHP mail() function on localhost?

Comment: [php mail setup in xampp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4653086/3770448)

Comment: Even if you do not want Gmail, you will need a working SMTP server anyway. You have to either rent one, or setup your own on a VPS.

Answer (score 1):

if your  configure like this  `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` and `c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini` for gmail to send mail.
now in `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` find out  `extension=php_openssl.dll` and remove the semicolon from the beginning of that line to make SSL working for gmail for localhost.

file find `[mail function]` in `php.ini` and change

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = my-gmail-id@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

and open it `C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini`. Replace all the existing code in `sendmail.ini` with bellow code

[sendmail]

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
auth_password=my-gmail-password
force_sender=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
```

Comment: I don't want to use Gmail or other, I would to use the native mail() function, without using any real email address.