# Custom HTML email form

Tags: php, html

I am looking to make a form that basically  sends a conformation email with a persons selected options back to them. For example if the site was designed for buying marbles. The user could choose form yellow, red, blue, green and orange marbles. Say the user picks yellow, red, and blue. Then the user gets an email saying `"Thanks for purchasing..." 
 Here is your confirmation:
 yellow marbles
 red marbles
 blue marbles`

So basically that is what I am trying to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please post your existing code so that We can help you! thanks **+1**

Comment: Have you already worked on some code we can comment on?

Comment: I really don't have any code yet. Just been looking for a starting point

Comment: It is nice that you shared this with community, but what is the question indeed? You should explore more, try [this link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-code-a-signup-form-with-email-confirmation--net-6860), or [this one](http://www.phpcontactform.com/sending-confirmation-email.html)

Answer (score 1):

Look into using PHP's [mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Also, [here's a previous Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379238/send-email-with-php-from-html-form-on-submit-with-the-same-script) with answers that will help you

Comment: Thats a comment, not an answer!

Comment: Thank You! However after putting in my email in the code and sending a message nothing has came through yet

Comment: According to the top answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php), the mail function will not work on your local server. To get it to work locally, you need to [set up an SMTP server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652566/php-mail-setup-in-xampp).

Comment: If it's not sending emails take a look at this troubleshoot checklist: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1658064/174368