# Send an email with PHP

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send an email when the 'Send Email' button is pressed, but the following code won't send anything to my email:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<form action="email.php" method="post"> 
<input value="Send Email" name="email" type="submit">
</form>
 <?php
   if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
   $msg = 'hello';
   mail('example@gmail.com', 'Sample', $msg); 
                               }                              
 ?>
</html>
```

Any idea on how to make it work?

Comment: are you testing this locally or on your website?

Comment: From the local host, I have saved it as email.php

Comment: There are tester programmes with which you test if emails are sent. After that problem is not in your code and have to ask your ISP, or use middleware services, such as sendgrid ;)

Comment: @Mary E yeay email usually doesn't work locally unless your willing to put in alot of afford i suggest just test it on your website your code should work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php

Comment: @herriekrekel,thanks so it is not working because I am running it on a local server

Comment: @MaryE yup it's always a pain getting it to work on a local server if you just upload the file to your website it should work and save you some time in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

Use the following PHP code to send the email

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Mail function will not work in Local server.You need to config SMTP on your local server. Take a look at this similar post,

[php mail setup in xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652566/php-mail-setup-in-xampp)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335273/how-to-send-an-email-using-php

Comment: Thank you, so I guess it is not working because I am running it on a local server.

Comment: Yes that may be case...Please read the link shared by Nana or me in the answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
         $to = "someemail.com"
         $subject = "This is subject";

         $message = "<b>This is message.</b>";
         $message .= "<h1>This is headline.</h1>";

         $header = "From:abc@somedomain.com \r\n";

         $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
         $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

         $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);

         if( $retval == true )
         {
            echo "Message sent successfully...";
         }
         else
         {
            echo "Message could not be sent...";
         }
      ?>
```