# Password Reset in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email-verification

I have a user system with user registration and user login. on the login page there is a password reset button and on the password rest button the following codes are there but nothing happens when I try to send a password rest link.

**CONTROLLER:**

```
function resetPasswordUser()
    {
        $status = '';

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('login_email','Email','trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->forgotPassword();
        }
        else 
        {
            $email = $this->input->post('login_email');

            if($this->user_model->checkEmailExist($email))
            {
                $encoded_email = urlencode($email);

                $this->load->helper('string');
                $data['email'] = $email;
                $data['activation_id'] = random_string('alnum',15);
                $data['createdDtm'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $data['agent'] = getBrowserAgent();
                $data['client_ip'] = $this->input->ip_address();

                $save = $this->user_model->resetPasswordUser($data);                

                if($save)
                {
                    $data1['reset_link'] = base_url() . "resetPasswordConfirmUser/" . $data['activation_id'] . "/" . $encoded_email;
                    $userInfo = $this->user_model->getCustomerInfoByEmail($email);

                    if(!empty($userInfo)){
                        $data1["username"] = $userInfo[0]->username;
                        $data1["email"] = $userInfo[0]->email;
                        $data1["message"] = "Reset Your Password";
                    }

                    $sendStatus = resetPasswordEmail($data1);

                    if($sendStatus){
                        $status = "send";
                        setFlashData($status, "Reset password link sent successfully, please check mails.");
                    } else {
                        $status = "notsend";
                        setFlashData($status, "Email has failed, try again.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $status = 'unable';
                    setFlashData($status, "It seems an error while sending your details, try again.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $status = 'invalid';
                setFlashData($status, "This email is not registered with us.");
            }
            redirect('users/forgotPassword');
        }
    }

    // This function used to reset the password 
    function resetPasswordConfirmUser($activation_id, $email)
    {
        // Get email and activation code from URL values at index 3-4
        $email = urldecode($email);

        // Check activation id in database
        $is_correct = $this->user_model->checkActivationDetails($email, $activation_id);

        $data['email'] = $email;
        $data['activation_code'] = $activation_id;

        if ($is_correct == 1)
        {
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('newPassword', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('users/login');
        }
    }

    // This function used to create new password
    function createPasswordUser()
    {
        $status = '';
        $message = '';
        $email = $this->input->post("email");
        $activation_id = $this->input->post("activation_code");

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|max_length[20]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword','Confirm Password','trim|required|matches[password]|max_length[20]');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->resetPasswordConfirmUser($activation_id, urlencode($email));
        }
        else
        {
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $cpassword = $this->input->post('cpassword');

            // Check activation id in database
            $is_correct = $this->user_model->checkActivationDetails($email, $activation_id);

            if($is_correct == 1)
            {                
                $this->user_model->createPasswordUser($email, $password);

                $status = 'success';
                $message = 'Password changed successfully';
            }
            else
            {
                $status = 'error';
                $message = 'Password changed failed';
            }

            setFlashData($status, $message);

            redirect("users/login");
        }
    }
```

**MODEL:**

```
function checkEmailExist($email)
    {
        $this->db->select('id');
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $this->db->where('isDeleted', 0);
        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    /**
     * This function used to insert reset password data
     * @param {array} $data : This is reset password data
     * @return {boolean} $result : TRUE/FALSE
     */
    function resetPasswordUser($data)
    {
        $result = $this->db->insert('reset_password', $data);

        if($result) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This function is used to get customer information by email-id for forget password email
     * @param string $email : Email id of customer
     * @return object $result : Information of customer
     */
    function getCustomerInfoByEmail($email)
    {
        $this->db->select('id, email, username');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('isDeleted', 0);
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();
    }

    /**
     * This function used to check correct activation deatails for forget password.
     * @param string $email : Email id of user
     * @param string $activation_id : This is activation string
     */
    function checkActivationDetails($email, $activation_id)
    {
        $this->db->select('id');
        $this->db->from('reset_password');
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $this->db->where('activation_id', $activation_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows;
    }

    // This function used to create new password by reset link
    function createPasswordUser($email, $password)
    {
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $this->db->where('isDeleted', 0);
        $this->db->update('users', array('password'=>getHashedPassword($password)));
        $this->db->delete('reset_password', array('email'=>$email));
    }
```

**VIEW:**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <?php echo validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">', ' <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button></div>'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $error = $this->session->flashdata('error');
    $send = $this->session->flashdata('send');
    $notsend = $this->session->flashdata('notsend');
    $unable = $this->session->flashdata('unable');
    $invalid = $this->session->flashdata('invalid');
    if($error)
    {
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error'); ?>                    
        </div>
    <?php }

    if($send)
    {
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <?php echo $send; ?>                    
        </div>
    <?php }

    if($notsend)
    {
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <?php echo $notsend; ?>                    
        </div>
    <?php }

    if($unable)
    {
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <?php echo $unable; ?>                    
        </div>
    <?php }

    if($invalid)
    {
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <?php echo $invalid; ?>                    
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>users/resetPasswordUser" method="post">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="login_email" required />
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
        </div><!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" value="Submit" />
        </div><!-- /.col -->
      </div>
    </form>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>users/login">Login</a><br>
  </div><!-- /.login-box-body -->
</div><!-- /.login-box -->
```

**CONSTANT:**

```
define('EMAIL_FROM',                            'xxxx@gmail.com');      // e.g. email@example.com
define('EMAIL_BCC',                             'xxxx@gmail.com');      // e.g. email@example.com
define('FROM_NAME',                             'CTL ');    // Your system name
define('EMAIL_PASS',                            'Your email password'); // Your email password
define('PROTOCOL',                              'smtp');                // mail, sendmail, smtp
define('SMTP_HOST',                             'smtp.gmail.com');      // your smtp host e.g. smtp.gmail.com
define('SMTP_PORT',                             '25');                  // your smtp port e.g. 25, 587
define('SMTP_USER',                             'Your smtp user');      // your smtp user
define('SMTP_PASS',                             'Your smtp password');  // your smtp password
define('MAIL_PATH',                             '/usr/sbin/sendmail');
```

**QUESTION UPDATE**
I changed my view to load out my errors and what I get is "Email has failed, try again." Error for mail not sent. Thanks

Comment: `$sendStatus = resetPasswordEmail($data1);`  Where is this defined?

Comment: where your  method forgotPassword()

Comment: $sendStatus = resetPasswordEmail($data1); is in my helper

Comment: You meant to say email is not sent?

Comment: You should load your view first I think that in your forgotPassword(); method which you did not defined

Comment: When you click your password reset button at first you should load your  view

Comment: I have updated the view and written what the update is for. Thanks

Comment: and I am running the application on MAMP server(localhost)

Comment: Did you try to print and see if you are getting all the data you need to reset the password?? if yes then did you try to check if you are able to send email?

Comment: I think the problem is with the CONSTANTS but I cant figure it out and I am using localhost

Comment: try with following :
Port = 465
Host = smtp.gmail.com
SMTPAuth = true
SMTPDebug = 1
SMTPSecure = 'ssl'

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it looks like you are using a localhost server. Localhost servers cannot send emails out IIRC. To test sending emails, you have to have a server that has access to the real world (and the feature has to be enabled on that server).

Comment: how do i configure the Constants if i am to use a real server?

Comment: This is for XAMPP, but see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652566/php-mail-setup-in-xampp. It essentially looks like you have to install a smtp server on top of your local server (or use a server that has smtp installed). For the constants, you just change the smtp host and port depending on your specific install.

Comment: Right, I was just showing it was possible. You could also set up a google smtp server (with a username and password) and do the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555145/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-with-codeigniter-email-library.

Comment: My original answer still stands, however. Unless you add something to your local server, or move to a server that supports SMTP (heroku or something like that), your emails will never send.

Comment: how do i configure the Constants if i am to use a real server??