# configure my mail constants in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to configure my mail constants in codeigniter to use local host. any ideas on what this parameters should be. I got this constant from a demo link. Thanks in advance
 **CONSTANT:**

```
 define('EMAIL_FROM',                            'xxxx@gmail.com');      // e.g. email@example.com
    define('EMAIL_BCC',                             'xxxx@gmail.com');      // e.g. email@example.com
    define('FROM_NAME',                             'XXX ');    // Your system name
    define('EMAIL_PASS',                            'Your email password'); // Your email password
    define('PROTOCOL',                              'smtp');                // mail, sendmail, smtp
    define('SMTP_HOST',                             'smtp.gmail.com');      // your smtp host e.g. smtp.gmail.com
    define('SMTP_PORT',                             '25');                  // your smtp port e.g. 25, 587
    define('SMTP_USER',                             'Your smtp user');      // your smtp user
    define('SMTP_PASS',                             'Your smtp password');  // your smtp password
    define('MAIL_PATH',                             '/usr/sbin/sendmail');
```

Comment: Refer  Documentation : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
define('EMAIL_FROM',                            'xxxxx@gmail.com');     // e.g. email@example.com
define('EMAIL_BCC',                             'xxxxx@gmail.com');     // e.g. email@example.com
define('FROM_NAME',                             'xxxx');    // Your system name
define('EMAIL_PASS',                            '');    // Your email password
define('PROTOCOL',                              'sendmail');                // mail, sendmail, smtp
define('SMTP_HOST',                             '');        // your smtp host e.g. smtp.gmail.com
define('SMTP_PORT',                             '');                    // your smtp port e.g. 25, 587
define('SMTP_USER',                             '');        // your smtp user
define('SMTP_PASS',                             '');    // your smtp password
define('MAIL_PATH',                             '/usr/sbin/sendmail');
```

reference [Password Reset in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285443/password-reset-in-codeigniter?noredirect=1#comment77533946_45285443)