# mail() not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing error

Tags: php, html, server, xampp

I made a form to send an email using php
and i got this error

```
    <b>Warning</b>: mail(): &quot;sendmail_from&quot;
 not set in php.ini or custom &quot;From:&quot;
 header missing in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP-Contact-Form\messege.php</b>



$reciver = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "form : $name <$email>?";
$body = "Name : $name \n Email : $email \n Phone : $phone \n Website : $website";
$sender = "From : $email";
    if(mail($reciver,$subject,$body,$sender)){

    }else{echo "Failed To Send Your Message !
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution : You need a SMTP  Server to send emails using php because mail() function requires a MTA(Mail Transfer Agent)
to work and it will not work if you use a local server like XAMPP.

1.You Can Setup SMTP on XAMPP locally .. see this question for more info [How to setup mail in XAMPP locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652566/how-to-setup-mail-in-xampp-locally)

2.You can use PHPMailer class at https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer it allows you to use the mail function or use a SMTP server transparently

3.Use  Swift mailer https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html